# Using ternary operator/conditional on select on dynamic linq

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, dynamic-linq

I am looking to do a linq query with Dynamic Linq library, but I am trying to select a property which is an `IEnumerable<T>` collection which throws an exception when calling the `Sum()` function in dynamic linq. I am wondering if I could say something like this:

```cs
queryable.Select("new (Sum(collection == null ? 0 : collection.Count) as Total)")
```

because

```cs
Select("new (Sum(np(Contestants.Count, 0)) as Total)")
```

returns a null reference exception

Comment: I don't know dynamic linq very well. In "normal" linq you would say `.DefaultIfEmpty(0)` before sum. Maybe this helps.

Comment: @Klamsi https://dynamic-linq.net/advanced-null-propagation it doesnt have the same syntax

Comment: Your `Where` operator has no sense. Write the same in pure C# and you will be surprised.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yeah I realizer i meant to write Select

Comment: And again string inside `Select` is incorrect. What are you trying to achieve?  Using dynamic linq is bad taste for me. Everything can be generated via expression tree.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv [_Dynamic Linq_](https://dynamic-linq.net/) is a set of extensions to Linq that adds `String`-based overloads to `.Select` and other Linq methods. _"Everything can be generated via expression tree"_ - not _everything_...

Comment: Believe me, almost everything. Dynamic Linq uses expression tree generation under hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `np` (NullPropagation) is used correctly, but `Sum` can only be used if you group. (Just like normal Linq)

A possible working code example could be:

```cs
public class X
{
    public string Key { get; set; } = null!;

    public List<Y>? Contestants { get; set; }
}

public class Y
{
}
```

```cs
var q = new[]
{
    new X { Key = "x" },
    new X { Key = "a" },
    new X { Key = "a", Contestants = new List<Y> { new Y() } }
}.AsQueryable();
var groupByKey = q.GroupBy("Key");
var selectQry = groupByKey.Select("new (Key, Sum(np(Contestants.Count, 0)) As TotalCount)").ToDynamicList();
```

Debug result:
[image]